# Selenium Grid - remote control connections to hub - fail to register, but build successfully

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I've successfully run a Selenium Grid on my local machine, and I've moved it to a server (windows Server 2008 R2).

The server instance has run successfully with locally launched agents
The server hosted console is visible over the internet

However, when I create a new remote control on a different machine, they build successfully but they do not register with the hub.

The command line is:

```
ant -Dport=6601 -Dhost=<ip address of my box> -DhubURL=http://ab.cdefg.ca:4444/wd/hub* -Denvironment"firefox" launch-remote-control
```

I've also used my hostname as a replacement for my ip name (pc78.subdomain.domain.ca)

If I do not specify the Denvironment, I get the following back:

```
      C:\Sgrid\selenium-grid-1.0.8>ant -Dport=6601 -Dhost=pcname.subdomain.domain.ca -Dhu
    bURL=http://ab.cdefg.ca:4444/wd/hub* launch-remote-control
    Buildfile: C:\Sgrid\selenium-grid-1.0.8\build.xml

    launch-remote-control:
         [java] Sep 15, 2011 3:37:11 PM com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol
    .RegistrationRequest execute
         [java] INFO: Registering to http://ab.cdefg.ca.ca:4444/wd/hub*/registration
    -manager/register
         [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could no
    t register successfuly to http://ab.cdefg.ca.ca:4444/wd/hub*/registration-manage
    r/register with environment '*firefox'. Most likely this environment is not defi
    ned on the hub.
         [java]     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol.RegistrationRequ
    est.execute(RegistrationRequest.java:29)
         [java]     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol.SelfRegisteringR
    emoteControl.register(SelfRegisteringRemoteControl.java:29)
         [java]     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.remotecontrol.SelfRegisteringR
    emoteControlLauncher.main(SelfRegisteringRemoteControlLauncher.java:27)

    BUILD FAILED
    C:\Sgrid\selenium-grid-1.0.8\build.xml:90: Java returned: 1

Total time: 1 second
```

If do specify the Denvironment, I get the following back:

```
C:\Sgrid\selenium-grid-1.0.8>ant -Dport=6601 -Dhost=pcname.sub.domain.ca -Dhu
bURL=http://ab.cdefg.ca:4444 -Denvironment"firefox" launch-remote-control
Buildfile: C:\Sgrid\selenium-grid-1.0.8\build.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

C:\Sgrid\selenium-grid-1.0.8>
```

However, the console does not recognize or utilize this agent. Nor is this agent visible on http://localhost:4444/console

So I thought, I'll reverse it and use my local as a server and try and register the server as a remote control, but the same problem repeated itself, command line success, but functionally no activity. Sounds like a network problem, so I booted up a third machine, installed and tested selenium grid (works). Console is visible from my laptop, running on my desktop, via ipaddress:4444/console.

I then launched a remote control, had the same problem. Okay, I then turn off the firewall on my local desktop (treating it as my server) and my laptop (treating it as a remote). Same problem.

Finally, thinking maybe the existence of a local console is messing with the remote launch, I reboot and run only the following:

```
ant -Dport=6601 -Dhost=<laptop ip> -DhubURL=http://<desktop ip>:4444 -Denvironment"firefox" launch-remote-control
```

Same problem.

Also I can ping the server from my desktop

Is there a setting I'm missing? It seems like everything in each instance is okay, and all of them have the same versions installed. Clearly something isn't getting from one place to the other, but I have no idea how to work around it when everything else seems okay. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need an "=" after the environment.  I.e., `-Denvironment="firefox"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ant -Dport=6666 -Dhost=pc78.subdomain.domain.ca -DhubURL=http://ab.cdef.ca:4444 launch-remote-control
```

Thanks for the kick start - dropping the "/wd/hub*" from the DhubURL and dropping the Denvironment all together actually got me working - thanks for the response. I